# Stop showing iOS 9 updates

Tags: beta-seed-program

I joined the beta program and installed iOS 9. I then unenrolled and did a restore to iOS 8.4 via iTunes. The problem is that my phone keeps prompting me to install the iOS 9 beta again. How do I get it to ignore updates relating to the beta program and leave me on iOS mainstream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings> General> Profile. 
Select the iOS 9 beta profile and delete it. Reboot your phone and you should get iOS 8.4 software up to date when you check for an update.